# Database 'commits' even after hibernate ehcache hit

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I am seeing commits to the database after getting a cache hit from ehcache.

When I look in the MYSQL SQL query logs I see this:

```
130730 17:20:23    53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
130730 17:20:24    53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
                   53 Query commit
```

This is obviously a big performance hit.  Any ideas what I have configured wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "cache hit from ehcache"? Please share the hibernate query you're making before these commits happen? Also, are you sure these commits don't come from some other operations happening in that app...thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this eventually.  The answer is here in the docs:

http://terracotta.org/documentation/3.7.4/enterprise-ehcache/distributed-hibernate#empty-db-connections

Using the LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy stopped the commits.